# what is the fasted way to communicate with serial port?

Tags: serial-port

I would like to know which programing language give me faster response to communcate with serial port in window platform

Asm?
java?
vb
C#
.NET
BASH
etc.

Comment: Serial ports are inherently slow, so pick the language that best suits the needs of the app.

Comment: As @dbasnett suggests programming language is totally irrelevant. 99.99999% of it is hardware and OS.

Comment: Make sure the data you send is LOUD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serial ports date from the stone-age of computing.  That's where you plugged-in your ASR-33 teletype to start banging in your Fortran program.  And wait a couple of hours to get your program compiled.

At a common baudrate of 9600, it takes a millisecond to transfer one byte.  A modern processor easily executes at least *3 million* instructions in that time span.  Even the most mundane interpreted scripting language has no trouble keeping up with that.  Such a processor also doesn't have a problem keeping up with a 10 gigabit/second network card.  Common enough for Ethernet, way out of reach for serial ports.

The real problem with serial ports is that they are **too slow**.  You cannot afford waiting for them, that would make your program too slow and unresponsive even for a human.  So pick a language that makes asynchronous programming easy.  Which can be very tricky to get right.  Any .NET language is certainly a good candidate.